How to troubleshoot "EOF" Docker pull error when working over VPN?
I am pulling image from the public Docker registry and getting the following error:
% docker pull ubuntu
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/latest": Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fubuntu%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": EOF

This happens on my work laptop, where all traffic is routed through an always-on VPN. I can temporarily disable it, but the goal is to make it work with the corporate VPN connected. If I disable VPN, docker pull works great.
Also, in my company there is a practice of decrypting TLS traffic, which is achieved by means of installing on user machines company's CA certificate, that serves as the new root for the decrypted traffic. TLS decryption happens only when working through VPN.
It is obvious that the VPN interferes with docker pull, but I am trying to figure out how exactly, to request a fix from the network team. Please, help me understand if the problem stems from TLS decryption practices or it's another network-related problem.
Firstly, the documentation of Docker Desktop for Mac says:

All trusted CAs (root or intermediate) are supported. Docker Desktop creates a certificate bundle of all user-trusted CAs based on the Mac Keychain, and appends it to Moby trusted certificates. So if an enterprise SSL certificate is trusted by the user on the host, it is trusted by Docker Desktop.

Based on this, TLS decryption should not be a problem, as the proper root CA certificate is already in the Mac's Keychain. However, as TLS decryption causes many other problems, it is still a suspect for me.
Secondly, it may be a pure networking problem. One issue was reported for Docker for Mac with exactly same error message, and all commenters agreed that the OP had problems with network. To exclude that, I am trying to manually download the image:
token=$(curl -s 'https://auth.docker.io/token?service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/ubuntu:pull' | jq -r .token)
man_digest=$(curl -s 'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/latest' -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" | jq '.manifests[] | select(.platform.architecture=="amd64")' | jq -r .digest)
blob_digest=$(curl -s "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/$man_digest" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" -H "Accept: application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json" | jq -r '.layers[0].digest')
curl -sL "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/blobs/$blob_digest" -H "Authorization: Bearer $token" > layer0.blob

It succeeds with VPN on. So it looks like all the mechanics required to pull an image works, and the registry is reachable. This resumes me back to certificate validation suspect, but at this point I don't know how to proceed further. The documentation is clear that Docker Desktop should use OS certificate store; and I am certain that this certificate is in the store, because I used the very same certificate to fix SSL validation in other tools (pip, poetry, curl, etc).
There is also a possibility that the problem is neither of the two and something else. Please suggest the next troubleshooting steps.

Have you tried restarting docker after the VPN is running?

Sure, I restarted it a few times..
